# Multiple filtro con vuejs en laravel

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, vuejs

Estimados quiero filtrar varios checkbox ( ejemplo : valor1 valor2 valor3) en una tabla y estoy utilizando filter pero cuando el array se incrementa no me filtra.

```
  clientFilter: function() {
      this.restul=  this.cliente.filter(item =>
        item.direcciones.includes(this.array)
      );
    },
```

Estoy buscando por muchos lados pero no encuentro una solucion..

Answer (score 2):

Si `this.array` es un array, `.includes()` no va a funcionar porque acepta un solo valor como argumento, si lo que quieres es filtrar todos los items del array `cliente` que en el array de `direcciones` contengan otro array (`this.array`), podrías usar `.every()`:

```js
const cliente = [{direcciones: [1, 2, 3]},{direcciones:[3, 4, 5]},{direcciones: [6, 7, 8]}];
const array = [3, 4, 5];

const res = cliente.filter(item =>
  array.every((e) => item.direcciones.includes(e))
);

console.log(res);
```

Esto funcionaría de forma similar a `.includes()` pero con arrays, si el array con el que comparamos, `direcciones` en este caso, tiene mas elementos pero incluye el que buscamos lo va a dar como resultado.

Comment: Emeeus, esta bien ...estoy probando el script y funciona cuando el valor del array es uno solo, cuando son dos no me devuelve nada, me devuelve un array vacio.

Comment: Tendrías que pasar que estás testeando exactamnete, recuerda que esto verifica si array esta incluido en algun direcciones.

Comment: Claro, si por ejemplo..necesito que me devuelva dos clientes distintos pero con las mismas direcciones..ese es el problema. EL script funciona cuando el array coincide completamente o parcialmente, pero cuando comparas valores de distintos array no funciona.

Comment: el tema es como tiene que ser la coincidencia, porque cambiando every por some podría ser lo que buscas.